# How to change file-sorting in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, sorting

I'm having a small problem with files being loaded in the wrong order, which is quite important for my app. Say I have the following files:
`a1 - a50,` the sorting won't be from smallest to largest, but will be like this:

```
a1, a10..
a2, a20..
a3, a30..
a4, a40..
a5, a50..
```

I've tried naming all files below a11 to `a_1, a_2` etc. and the sorting is fixed, but for some reason my app doesn't catch this new order, and simply loads `a1, a2, a3`, etc., even after a fresh install of the app.
How can I fix this sorting issue?

Comment: Try to rename into a01-a09

Comment: It's times like these I wish I didn't have these random brain-farts.. I renamed the files, sorting is fine, but for some reason my app (even after a re-install) is still loading a1, whereas the inspector says it's a01.

Comment: Try to clean project. Maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up my project as per @ArtyomKiriliyk 's suggestion, and found out my R.java file would not generate. So after heavy toiling with trial and error, I found out I had a file with a double extension (say, .jpg.jpg), so  had a faulty name which messed things up for me.
Everything works as it should now! Once again Artyom, thanks!